# Installing openstack with Juju and MAAS

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I'm currently trying to deploy an Openstack cluster using Juju and MAAS on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have 6 servers, one allocated as my MAAS server and the rest are enlisted and commissioned by the MAAS server. I ran the command

```
sudo openstack-install
```

and upon providing all the relevant info that it asks for, the window shows me that it has successfully Bootstrapped Juju and Prepared Landscape. The issue is when it tries to deploy landscape. It times out at 45 minutes and the error when I do a

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/juju/machine-0.log
```

it shows me the following:

```
2016-07-13 22:33:40 WARNING juju.state allwatcher.go:351 getting a public address for unit "landscape-server/0" failed: "public no address"
2016-07-13 22:33:40 WARNING juju.state allwatcher.go:355 getting a private address for unit "landscape-server/0" failed: "private no address"
2016-07-13 22:33:45 ERROR juju.state.unit unit.go:738 unit postgresql/0 cannot get assigned machine: unit "postgresql/0" is not assigned to a machine
2016-07-13 22:33:45 WARNING juju.state allwatcher.go:351 getting a public address for unit "postgresql/0" failed: "unit postgresql/0 cannot get assigned machine: unit \"postgresql/0\" is not assigned to a machine"
2016-07-13 22:33:45 ERROR juju.state.unit unit.go:748 unit postgresql/0 cannot get assigned machine: unit "postgresql/0" is not assigned to a machine
2016-07-13 22:33:45 WARNING juju.state allwatcher.go:355 getting a private address for unit "postgresql/0" failed: "unit postgresql/0 cannot get assigned machine: unit \"postgresql/0\" is not assigned to a machine"
2016-07-13 22:33:50 WARNING juju.state allwatcher.go:351 getting a public address for unit "postgresql/0" failed: "public no address"
2016-07-13 22:33:50 WARNING juju.state allwatcher.go:355 getting a private address for unit "postgresql/0" failed: "private no address"
2016-07-13 22:33:55 WARNING juju.state allwatcher.go:351 getting a public address for unit "rabbitmq-server/0" failed: "public no address"
2016-07-13 22:33:55 WARNING juju.state allwatcher.go:355 getting a private address for unit "rabbitmq-server/0" failed: "private no address"
```

The shell session on which I ran the openstack-install command originally shows an [INFO] bar with "Downloading latest Landscape Autopilot bundle..." in it.

When I tried to boostrap Juju independently (without the sudo openstack-install command) and download the landscape-dense-maas bundle, I am getting the exact same error of "public no address/private no address". Strangely enough, I am able to deploy the juju-gui charm successfully and access the web GUI, but no other charms or services (I tried it with wordpress and hadoop and got the same error).

The network configuration for MAAS seems to be correct in that MAAS is having no problem with finding nodes and deploying Ubuntu on them. Each node has 2 NICs and one is connected to a Private Network and one is connected to the external network

commands.log file attached [here](http://pastebin.com/faTb7h92)

Thanks for reading and please feel free to ask for more information.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Please, provide also your hardware details to the end of the body. Please, also include the version details of the appropriate softwares.

Comment: Can you SSH into any of the MAAS nodes after successfully deploying them without Juju? It looks like you might need to use sshuttle or some other sort of routing/proxying if your client machine is not on the same network as the nodes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm able to ssh into them because they are assigned an IP address by the MAAS node as they are being deployed. They have 2 interfaces, one reserved for the Private/PXE network and one for the External connection. Both interfaces are assigned an address as during deployment and I'm able to ssh into the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert with openstack but I might know the solution to your issue. When I deployed openstack I had a similar issue where the proxy on my network was interfering with the download of Landscape. It was odd because I was able to ssh into a node and install packages with `apt-get` but when I tried to deploy openstack the Landscape setup failed. After some troubleshooting I found that the download was failing. I temporarily removed the proxy and it worked. Hope this helps!